# Is anyone heavily using StreamInsight?

Tags: c#, sql-server, events, real-time, streaminsight

Is anyone currently using [StreamInsight](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/complex-event-processing.aspx) (other than just demoing)? If so, how is it currently working in your environment? We are currently looking at the possibility of implementing it, but none of us know much about it or if it is really a viable option.

I can't find any pricing quotes, just the downloads (latest version looks like 1.2).

Any tips/suggestions/comments would be greatly welcomed. We are currently using .Net and SQL Server so it seems like it would be a good fit in our environment.

Comment: What are you looking to use it for?

Comment: Hi @Sean pulling data out of a stream (XML Messages) so that we can have close to real-time analysis of those messages

Comment: Re licensing: It is part of sql server licensing, so look for that one there. Basically a "free add on product" if you have the needed sql server licenses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I briefly considered StreamInsight for one project, but I couldn't use it due to high costs. My suggestion would be to take a look at [openPDC](http://www.openpdc.com). It's an application written by some guys from the TVA and geared towards the power industry, but it can accomplish similar tasks to StreamInsight. To use the product, you would need to write an adapter that can be loaded into the application using the built-in plugin architecture. The adapter could examine XML messages very quickly and take an action in response. I believe this application could support your situation, as it is used to monitor measurements for the power grid that arrive every 33ms.